# Remove empty space from matplotlib bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I plot two bar plots to the same ax, where the x axis contains values from 0 downwards. However, I have significant gaps in my data (like from 0 to -15), and would like to remove the empty space, so that the axis goes from 0 to -15 with no space in between - show on this image:

[image]

Ideally I would like to do this for all gaps. I have tried both `plt.axis('tight')` and `fig.tight_layout()`, but neither of them have worked.

Edit: sample code for a small example

```py
keys = [0, -15, -16, -17]
values = [3, 5, 2, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1)
fig.tight_layout()

ax.bar(keys, values, 0.8, color='g', align='center')

ax.set_xticks(keys)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The easiest way to resolve the issue is plot `values` against an `x` that is a range corresponding to the `len` of `keys`, and then change the `xticklabels`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

keys = [0, -15, -16, -17]
values = [3, 5, 2, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# create the xticks locations
x = range(len(keys))

ax.bar(x, values, 0.8, color='g', align='center')

# set the ticks and labels
ax.set_xticks(x)
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(keys)
```

[image]

### Sorting

```py
keys = [0, -15, -16, -17]
values = [3, 5, 2, 1]

# zip, sort and unpack
keys, values = zip(*sorted(zip(keys, values)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# create the xticks locations
x = range(len(keys))

ax.bar(x, values, 0.8, color='g', align='center')

# set the ticks and labels
ax.set_xticks(x)
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(keys)
```

[image]